# ng-repeat track by $index not working with pagination

Tags: angularjs, filter, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-track-by

I'm working with ng-repeat + Filter + Pagination(ui-bootstrap)

1- ng-repeat + filter is working fine :

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="target in targets | filter:search track by $index">
```

2- ng-repeat + filter + pagination is working fine too:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="target in targets | filter:search  | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize  | limitTo: pageSize ">
```

3- the problem is when I combine ng-repeat + Filter + Pagination + track by $index

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="target in targets | filter:search  | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize  | limitTo: pageSize track by $index">
```

I get my index value restart from 0 to 4 in each page

[here is a screen shot of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sco0P.jpg)

Any Idea about the correct order for "track by $index" ! where should I place it?

Answer (score 2):

Finaly I 've fixed my issue with another logic, I was using track by $index for editing selected row field in my table like this:

```
<td><input class="todo" type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="updateTarget(targets[$index])" ng-model="target.YEAR"></td>
<td><input class="todo" type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="updateTarget(targets[$index])" ng-model="target.MONTH"></td>
```

Now I deleted track by $index from my ng-repeat, and I changed my td to:

```
<td><input style="width:40px" class="todo" type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="updateTarget(target)" ng-model="target.YEAR"></td>
<td><input style="width:40px" class="todo" type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="updateTarget(target)" ng-model="target.MONTH"></td>
```

So on ng-change , my update function will be called with all the object as a parameter, no need to $index to determine the current object.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the correct sintax is something like:

`<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index | my filter....">`

hope this helps

Comment: yes that's true , but in my case the pagination might be causing the issue,  in my controller i have :                                             todoApp.filter('startFrom', function(){
        return function(data, start){
            return data.slice(start);
        }
    });